# Using different displays opengl

Tags: python, c++, opengl, glut, pyopengl

I'm trying to write a program in either python or C++ using opengl that will allow me to control different displays. Currently I have three different displays, I have the computer monitor, a LCD and a DLP all hooked up to my computer. I want to control each screen separately, and I want to full screen them all so they go black. Currently when I try to use glutfullscreen() in only makes the computer monitor black, and I can't control the other two screen.

In my set up I have removed the backlight from a LCD screen and I'm projecting onto it with a DLP projector to increase my dynamic range. I'm trying to write software to align the two image. I have it all working in MATLAB with mgl. But I don't know where to go with C++.

I need to be able to control the pixels of where each image is displayed, but I can't access the other two screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like SDL2 or GLFW3 for multimonitor support.  They'll let you query the number of monitors and their sizes, as well as let you create multiple windows to cover them.